# rerender Backbone views without losing references to dom

Tags: backbone.js, view, rendering

I have the following problem with backbone and I'd like to know what strategy is the more appropriated

I have a select control, implemented as a Backbone view, that initially loads with a single option saying "loading options". So I load an array with only one element and I render the view.

The options will be loaded from a collection, so I fire a fetch collection.

Then I initialize a component that is in charge of displaying in line errors for every field. So I save a reference of the dom element of the combo.

When the fetch operation is finally ready, I rerender the control with all the options loaded from the collection.

To render the view I user something like this:

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
  return this;
}
```

pretty standard backbone stuff

the problem is that after rendering the view for the second time the reference of the dom is no longer valid,

perhaps this case is a bit strange, but I can think of lots of cases in which I have to re-render a view without losing their doms references (a combo that depends on another combo, for example)

So I wonder what is the best approach to re-render a view without losing all the references to the dom elements inside the view...

Comment: My 2 cents... You should never use model.attributes directly, that is why you have model.get('something') and model.set('something', value) or model.set({some: a, thing: b}).

Comment: What's wrong with using model.attributes ONLY to read it? I do understand why I should use Model#Set (to trigger the change event and other stuff) but the Model#Get doesn't do much. Have a look at the code, it's just a : return this.attributes[attr];

Comment: And, as far as I've seen, there is no model.getAll().  model.attributes seems to be the only way to do that.

Comment: At some point your programmers will write using "model.attributes" instead of doing "model.set" because your lack of consistency.

Comment: I see your point Erick, but how would you rewrite the former example?

Comment: @opensas In order to keep "attributes" out of the sight (because it is mainly for internal use) we do the following: 

`
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
  return this;
}
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of `Backbone.View` is to encapsulate the access to a certain DOM subtree to a single, well-defined class. It's a poor Backbone practice to pass around references to DOM elements, those should be considered internal implementation details of the view.

Instead you should have your views communicate directly, or indirectly via a mediator.

Direct communication might look something like:

```
var ViewA = Backbone.View.extend({
  getSelectedValue: function() {
    return this.$(".combo").val()
  }
});

var ViewB = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.viewA = options.viewA;
  },
  doSomething: function() {
    var val = this.viewA.getSelectedValue();
  }
});

var a = new ViewA();
var b = new ViewB({viewA:a});
```

And indirect, using the root `Backbone` object as a mediator:

```
var ViewA = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "change .combo" : "selectedValueChanged"
  },
  selectedValueChanged: function() {
    //publish
    Backbone.trigger('ViewA:changed', this.$('.combo').val());
  }
});

var ViewB = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    //subscribe
    this.listenTo(Backbone, 'ViewA:changed', this.doSomething);
  },
  doSomething: function(val) {
    //handle 
  }
});

var a = new ViewA();
var b = new ViewB();
```

The above is very generic, of course, but the point I'm trying to illustrate here is that you shouldn't have to worry whether the DOM elements are swapped, because no other view should be aware of the element's existence. If you define interfaces between views (either via method calls or mediated message passing), your application will be more maintainable and less brittle.

Comment: Excellent answer fencliff!!! This should be right in backbone.js definition of a view. I think that these (not so) little conceptual things are what makes backbones hard to start with.

Comment: So,as a general rule, I should only use references to dome elements:    


1. when passing the el element in a constructor.  

2. to reference any dom subtree elements from the view itself (I guess I should also overwrite View#setElement to update all internal references).  

3. NOWHERE ELSE - that way I could destroy the dom view and regenerate it again everytime when rendering without worrying for broken dom references (in fact, the view should take care of updating their internal references).  

do you agree with such a rule?